# What level and resources would it take to perform the musical number introducing Genie in Aladdin (Disney animated film)?

Tags: optimization, pathfinder-2e

## WIP; Do not reopen yet

This question is essentially just for fun, but could be an interesting reference for making an entrance in an exciting and fantastical way.

What spells, items, etc. would it require to perform the musical number "Friend Like Me", complete with (either real or illusory/the appearance of):

- immediate disguises
- roast chicken and baklava
- short range teleportation
- illusion of a room full of gold,
- animated objects as backup dancers
- 

What is the minimum level to accomplish this, using the wealth-by-level table and standard spell slots for one day*, assuming you are willing to spend all your starter resources on this endeavor (and would you have enough items left over to get basic utility items such as appropriate armor, weapon rune(s), and/or a staff)?

Some clarifications:

- The best answer(s) will cover the most scenarios in the scene, replicated as close as possible

  - You should be able to sing fairly well, regularly able to meet the Standard DC for your level
- This is about the 1992 animated film; however, I will try to award a bounty to any good answer that also covers the live-action adaptation (even if they are not the selected answer)
- *If there are any spells that last more than a day that can be pre-cast, you can do so
- You have as many uninterrupted rounds as needed as long as the production is continuing

  - E.G. you could take 3-5+ rounds to complete a sequence, but cannot take a 1-10 minute break mid-performance to set up the next part
- If you need a subject to play Aladdin, assume you have one willing humanoid to play the part
- There are no available objects to animate; you must bring your own and have them available quickly
- You do not need to live inside an oil lamp, nor do you need to shrink yourself to fit in one

Comment: Just for clarification: you mean the "Prince Ali" song from the 1992 Disney animated film, is it correct?

Comment: @enkryptor yes - it appears my copy-paste notepad had a private file on it, not the song lyrics website...

Comment: Potential [reference](https://genius.com/Robin-williams-prince-ali-lyrics) when determining what will be needed (75 golden camels, _etc_). Note in particular the original song had "slaves, servants, and flunkies" while the live action lyrics have been updated to "ten-thousand servants and flunkies".  Thanks @VLAZ for pointing out the bad link.

Comment: -1 because this question is not self-contained. Question should include all the details needed to know what you are asking for,  so  *"any other bits I'm not remembering"* isn't nice. You are making people not only research answers, but also figure out what is the question.

Comment: Perhaps a link to a video of the relevant scene on YouTube would suffice? It'd be impractical to describe everything in a long and visually-complex musical number with words in the text of the question itself.

Comment: @GMJoe link decay is the reason why Stack Exchange forbids link-only answers. I don't think it's any different for questions.

Comment: @GMJoe also, if describing each element is too much, then describing each element *and how to achieve it* would be even worse, right?

Comment: @Mołot I understand why you think it could use more detail and will add more; I had to write this up on a deadline to make it to my RPG night. I actually meant "Friend Like Me", and am surprised I didn't name it. I'll at least add that much for now. I guess I thought describing *most* of the scenes from that number would suffice, but I can make a list of expectations while watching it, probably later today or tomorrow for sure.

Comment: In the meantime, I added my own VTC for more details. Oddly, I can't "Close" my own question without the votes to support it.

Comment: @Mołot If the concern is to avoid link decay, naming the song in question and the film it appears in should be enough to use as a reference. It's one of the most popular films Disney has every made; the scene will be available online in some form or another until the internet breaks down.

Comment: @GMJoe that's the lesser of two concerns. Second is, if list of all the elements of the show, with instructions how to achieve them, is not too much to ask for, then a list without these instructions, at most 1/4 as long I believe, and undoubtedly much shorter, wouldn't be too much either.